# Wseemann FFMPEG Player

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am not able to compile Weseemann FFMPEG Player. Getting below error.

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':library:buildFFmpeg'.
```

> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Users\lenovo\Downloads\Wseemann_New\FFmpegMediaPlayer-master3\FFmpegMediaPlayer-master\gradle\fmp-library\library\src\main\scripts\build-ffmpeg.sh''

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer

Comment: I have the same problem did you find any solution?